# WebDataRocks height as percent not working

Tags: css, pivot, webdatarocks

I just starting using WebDataRocks and can't seem to get the height to fill the window.  The documentation says it will (https://www.webdatarocks.com/doc/init-api-call), "The height of the pivot table in pixels or percent (500 by default)".

The below code snippet won't even render.

`var pivot = new WebDataRocks({
  container: 'wdr-component',
  height: 100%,
  beforetoolbarcreated: customizeToolbar,
  toolbar: true,
  report: {`

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To set the height of the pivot table in percent use string value.
For example,

```
height: '100%'
```

In order for pivot table's height to fill the window the parent's height must be 100%. Therefore, add the following CSS:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```